# How to get the assigned Azure Active Directory admin for SQL Server with PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I would like to get the currently assigned Active Directory admin name for a specific Azure SQL server with PowerShell script.

[image: Azure portal]

I thought that it will shows in the Resource properties but unfortunately not and I did not find any specific command for that.

Is there any way to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell command to get this information is Get-AzureRmSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator

Example from Microsoft docs -

```
Get-AzureRmSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -ServerName "Server01"
ResourceGroupName ServerName DisplayName ObjectId 
----------------- ---------- ----------- -------- 
ResourceGroup01   Server01   DBAs        40b79501-b343-44ed-9ce7-da4c8cc7353b
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/get-azurermsqlserveractivedirectoryadministrator?view=azurermps-6.7.0

Also, at least in your screenshot you don't have any admin set for the server. If you want to set that up first, before reading that info from PowerShell command, then follow the guidance here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure